# How to write logs to a file in a lagom application

Tags: docker, lagom

As part of deploying my lagom application to the kubernetes production environment, I am trying to publish all my logs to a file besides writing to the standard output. For this I created a `logback.xml` under resources directory adding file appender as per suggestion [here](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/SettingsLogger?&_ga=2.213361111.2140753749.1588672362-358831823.1573047181#Default-configuration).

```
<appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
    <file>${application.home:-.}/logs/application.log</file>
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%date [%level] from %logger in %thread - %message%n%xException</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>
```

But it is failing to create a log file in the container working directory. I get following error instead:

```
09:23:33,209 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.AsyncAppender[ASYNCSTDOUT] - Setting discardingThreshold to 51
09:23:33,209 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - About to instantiate appender of type [ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender]
09:23:33,213 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - Naming appender as [FILE]
09:23:33,217 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.NestedComplexPropertyIA - Assuming default type [ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder] for [encoder] property
09:23:33,220 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender[FILE] - File property is set to [./logs/application.log]
09:23:33,222 |-ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender[FILE] - Failed to create parent directories for [/opt/docker/./logs/application.log]
09:23:33,222 |-ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender[FILE] - openFile(./logs/application.log,true) call failed. java.io.FileNotFoundException: ./logs/application.log (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.FileNotFoundException: ./logs/application.log (No such file or directory)
    at  at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
```

I am not really sure why is it failing to create the log directory and the log file under container working directory.

```
demiourgos728@ca5fc4a4c1db:/opt/docker$ ls
bin  lib  share
```

I tried providing the read, write, execute permission on the container working directory as shown below but that didn't work either:

```
DockerChmodType.UserGroupWriteExecute
```

Please suggest.

- Docker base images conf: `dockerBaseImage := "adoptopenjdk/openjdk8"`.
- Whole log file [here](https://github.com/codingkapoor/intimations-platform/blob/k8s/employee-impl/src/main/resources/logback.xml).
- [K8S definitions](https://github.com/codingkapoor/intimations-platform/tree/k8s/deploy/k8s)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing to a file in a container is bad for two reasons:
1. Logs are available only within the container i.e.,would require to get into the container to see the logs
2. They are not available via `kubectl log` command
3. They are ephemeral in nature i.e., if container crashes, logs will disappear

Instead writing to STDOUT and STDERR is considered as best practise in a container environment. The logs written to STDOUT and STDERR are redirected by docker engine to a location in the node (/var/log/containers/). Moreover, these logs are also available via `kubectl logs` command.

Practically logs are not even preserved at even a node but are instead moved to a central logging system. You can read more about it [here](https://timber.io/blog/collecting-application-logs-on-kubernetes/).